# How can I pass a Polymer Object beetwen 2 custom elements

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm building a new webapp and I need to know how can I pass an object between 2 custom elements in polymer.

In the code below, I set the value of mydata in "my-child-element-1" and I need to see this value in "my-child-element-2"...I think that it's not very hard to do but i'm loosing my mind to find a good solution...

In my opinion, i should create a temporary object in "my-host-element" to share the value but i'm not convinced about this...

This is my code:

```
<dom-module id="my-host-element">
    <template>

        <my-child-element-1     mydata="{{mydata}}"></my-child-element-1>


        <my-child-element-2     mydata="{{mydata}}"></my-child-element-2>

    </template>

    <script>
    Polymer({

        is: "my-host-element",
        properties: 
        {
            mydata: {
                type: Object
            }
        }
      });

    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example looks like it should work without the host element needing a property, **if** the property on the child elements are set up correctly. Remember that Polymer's data binding syntax is basically syntactic sugar around firing and handling custom events. So take a look in child element 1 and make sure that you've set the property to notify when changed. For example:

```
Polymer({
    is: "my-child-element-1",
    properties: {
        mydata: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true // fire mydata-change CustomEvent on change
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! your solution is interesting but is necessary the notify flag in my-child-element-1 only? if i understand your question, i don't need of the object in the parent element...it's right?

Comment: I don't believe you need the mydata property in the parent.

Comment: I verified on my machine that you do not need the property defined in the parent element. The key is to have the notify: true in the child element.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I removed the data in the parent, i added the notify and clean the code...it seems works without problems! :) thanks! Ciao!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, afaik it is correct to have the parent element act as the mediator between the children, which means it needs to have its own property even if its only used for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) last question: from child to parent i should use "notify: true" as property in my child...it'right? So, how can i pass mydata from parent to second child?